# Simulating smoke in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

i want to simulate smoke in the gazebo. preliminary solution what i think of is i draw some very small particles in environment and simulate them in a way that smoke behaves.

what i want to know that is it possible in Gazebo to achieve that and secondly if yes then how come. Technical details or tutorial will be appreciated.

(p.s i am new to the ROS and gazebo plateform so keep things less complicated)

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30875/simulating-smoke-in-gazebo/) by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2012-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2012-04-01**:
For what purpose do you want to simulate the smoke? Is it just for visualization purposes or is it supposed to trigger a simulated smoke sensors? Not that I think I can help you very much, I am just curious!

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2012-04-01**:
There has been work simulating and tracking scent plumes in player/stage - http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5652518&tag=1

**Comment by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on 2012-04-03**:
@Goncalo
it is just for visualization purpose only.

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2012-04-03**:
@Zee-Q Ok! Cause I developed plumesim for ROS but it only displays the plume in rviz, and it is a 2D simulator for odor plumes, not for smoke. I'd love to upgrade it for 3D and maybe add some visualization for Gazebo if I get some time to learn how to use it!!!

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-04-07**:
Gazebo uses Ogre3D for visualization, so you can take a look at the rendering classes http://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/hg/file/955ea031a5b2/src/rendering if you want to try and implement something for visualizing smoke.    @goncalo-cabrita can you point us to your plumesim? seems interesting, thanks.

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2012-04-07**:
@hsu Sure, http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_plumesim I'm actually cooking plumesim 2.0 I'll take a look at the rendering classes to see if I can add some Gazebo features for the new version!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you can try Morse simulator with blender.

Here is the video of [Introduction to Smoke Simulation](http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/introduction-to-smoke-simulation).

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2012-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on 2012-04-03**:
but can i later on integrate it to my gazebo environment ?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-04-03**:
As I know,the answer is no. I'm still going to find a way to combine them together.